# React Native Styling problems

Tags: react-native, styling, react-native-stylesheet

I have problems with styling in React Native inside a nested view.

Desired Outcome:
[image]

my Design :
[image]

As you can see I have problems allocating the text horizontally

Code:

```
let width = Dimensions.get('window').width - 42;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardBorder: {
    marginTop: 25,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    borderColor: "grey",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  titleText: {
    ...FONT_SEMI_BOLD,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 17,
    flex: 1,
  },
  priceText: {
    ...FONT_SEMI_BOLD,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    fontSize: 17,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default class CardDetailScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <HeaderReturn />
        <View style={styles.cardBorder}>
          <Image
            style={{ height: width, width: width }}
            source={{ uri: testData[0].uri }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>{testData[0].name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceText}>{testData[0].price}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, it looks super simple but I just cannot get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to show the name on left side and price on right side of view. So you can try it this way,

```
priceText: {
    ...FONT_SEMI_BOLD,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 10,
    fontSize: 17,
},
```

Just mention your `marginLeft: 'auto'`. Also remove `justifyContent: "space-between",` from your parent view's style.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot, would you mind explaining, on why this works?

Comment: @Fredyonge well simply in a View with flex direction row if you give marginStart or marginLeft as auto to a View then it moves to the end of that view, which would be right for normal view and left for RTL.

Comment: Ah, well thats easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your styles.cardBorder to have `alignItems: 'center'` and `'width': '100%'`. I think your texts are centered in its container fine, but the container is not taking the full width. Maybe you only need `'width': '100%'`.

Comment: Hey ZenBoat! Thanks for you answer, unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried it on styles.Cardborder and on the container view of my <Text> .